# How to put a text to the center below of the image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make a meme generator. My code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os, random, datetime



TEXT_FOR_MEMES = [
    'Отдохнули аче',
    'Я бох а ты лох',
    'Дада пугай мы же богатые',
    'Именно поэтому донбасс может разволиться'
]

os.chdir('direction.')



def make_a_meme():

     im = Image.open('pics_for_memes\\' + random.choice(os.listdir('pics_for_memes'))) #opens a random picture


draw_text = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype('Lobster.ttf', size=65)

width = im.width
height = im.height


draw_text.text(
    (width / 2, height / 2),

    random.choice(TEXT_FOR_MEMES),

    fill=('#ffffff'),
    font=font
)

#im.save('pics_for_memes\\test.jpg')

im.show()


make_a_meme()
```

But it always puts the text differently. And I know why, so I wanna ask: How to find below of center of the screen and put text there correctly? It puts text FROM the center. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry for tab issues here, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most help. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize

```
import os
import random

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def make_a_meme():
    TEXT_FOR_MEMES = [
        'Отдохнули аче',
        'Я бох а ты лох',
        'Дада пугай мы же богатые',
        'Именно поэтому донбасс может разволиться'
    ]

    os.chdir('direction.')

    im = Image.open('pics_for_memes\\' + random.choice(os.listdir('pics_for_memes')))  # opens a random picture

    draw_text = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('Lobster.ttf', size=65)

    width = im.width
    height = im.height

    text = random.choice(TEXT_FOR_MEMES)
    text_size = draw_text.textlength(text, font=font)
    draw_text.text(
        ((width / 2) - (text_size / 2), height / 2),
        text,
        fill='#ffffff',
        font=font
    )

    # im.save('pics_for_memes\\test.jpg')

    im.show()


make_a_meme()
```

Comment: oMG!! Thank you! I wanted to make smth like that, but I didn't know how to find out a text's length :)